# How to run jQuery function AFTER the content is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have ajax function's on my page that run for specific seconds and update the data.Sample code;

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

   

                function loadPartialView() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("_MatchScore", "Home",new { match_id = Model.match.match_id })",
                    // <-- make a async request by GET
                    dataType: 'html', // <-- to expect an html response
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#matchScore').html(result);
                        }
                    });
            }

            $(function () {

                loadPartialView(); // first time

            // re-call the function each 5 seconds
            window.setInterval("loadPartialView()", 25000);

            });

            function loadPartialView2() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("_MatchStatus", "Home",new { match_id = Model.match.match_id })",
                    // <-- make a async request by GET
                    dataType: 'html', // <-- to expect an html response
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#matchA').html(result);
                    }
                });
            }

            $(function () {

                loadPartialView2(); // first time

                // re-call the function each 5 seconds
                window.setInterval("loadPartialView2()", 25000);

            });

    </script>
```

But how do i get the data from the model to be loaded on the page at first and then my update function's work ? I used document ready but it didn't work.

Comment: A small note: your `setInterval` is set for 25 seconds, not 5.

Comment: Little bit confusing - your title asks for *after* (in caps), but your question asks for "at first" (ie *before*)

Comment: @freedomn-m can you share sample code ?

Comment: Can you clarify *when* you want your code to run?  "How to run jquery function" and you want me to share that jquery function?  Share what "sample" code?  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I want the update functions to run after the general model of the page is loaded. When i enter the page, i don't want a whiteness and then the data to come.

Comment: Ah, you want the same code that runs in ajax to also load as part of your page.  Add this to your cshtml/razor code (not in javascript): `@Url.Partal("_MatchScore", "Home", new { match_id = Model.match.match_id })`

Comment: <div class="score-area margin-left-md margin-right-md font-size-32 font-weight-500" id="matchScore">
                                        @Url.Action("_MatchScore", "Home", new { match_id = Model.match.match_id})
                                    </div> I used this but it didn't work.

Comment: My bad - typo: should be `@Html.Partial...`  not `@Url` anything

Comment: Thank you.. Does this ajax keep cache on my page ? Will my page slow down after a while ? Is there a way to clean it ?